# How do I check if XML value is nil in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, null, xml-nil

In an XML document I have some address data..

```
<zip>08001</zip>
<zipPlus xsi:nil="true" />
```

and

```
<zip>08002</zip>
<zipPlus>4512</zipPlus>
```

On only want to bother displaying the zip plus value if there is a value to use. (for the purposes of this example, I don't care if its a correct zip plus format or not)

Trying to use the following snippet in an XSLT never seems to work right, and I think it has to do with how I am checking for the **xsl:nil** value

```
<EmployerZipCode>
      <xsl:value-of select="zip"/>
      <xsl:if test="zipPlus != @xsl:nil">
        <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="zipPlus"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$sepChar"/> <!--this is a comma -->
</EmployerZipCode>
```

The results I get are always

```
08001,
08002,
```

not

```
08001,
08002-4512,
```

What is the proper way to check for nil-led elements in XSLT? 
Are there any other ways to get around this problem and get the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more testing, none of answers given that involve checking the nil attribute work reliably.

I had to resort to using string-length() to get the result I needed.

```
<EmployerZipCode>
  <xsl:value-of select="zip"/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length(zipPlus) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="zipPlus"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="$sepChar"/>
</EmployerZipCode>
```

Comment: See my answer. I'm testing just with `not(zipPlus/@xsi:nil)` assuming that if the attribute is missing you want the zipplus. However @Jim-Garrison works either (even if in my test you need to replace prefix `xsl` with `xsi`).

Answer (score 6):

```
<xsl:if test="not(zipPlus/@xsi:nil='true')">
```

Comment: If @xsl:nil is present only when the value is "true", then use `not(zipPlus/@xsl:nil)` which tests for the existence of the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

In XSLT 2.0, for reasons I have never fully understood, there is a custom function

```
test="not(nilled(zipPlus))"
```

Comment: the xslt debugging in visual studio does not know about the nilled() function.

Comment: D'oh. just realized that VS2010 only supports XSLT 1.0. That's super lame. Thanks anyway @Michael Kay

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange that you didn't get it to work. Perhaps it might be you are missing namespace declaration or the prefix change `xsi` to `xsl` is an unseen typo in your transform. Check better. Here my test:

**XSLT 1.0** with **Saxon 6.5**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="test">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="EmployerZipCode">
        <EmployerZipCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="zip"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(zipPlus/@xsi:nil)">
                <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="zipPlus"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="','"/> <!--this is a comma -->
        </EmployerZipCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="test">
    <EmployerZipCode>
        <zip>08001</zip>
        <zipPlus xsi:nil="true" />
    </EmployerZipCode>
    <EmployerZipCode>
        <zip>08002</zip>
        <zipPlus>4512</zipPlus>
    </EmployerZipCode>
</test>
```

Produces:

```
08001,
08002-4512,
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

Source XML :

```
            <zipPlus xsi:nil="true"/>
                      or
            <zipPlus>123456</zipPlus>
```

XSLT :

```
            <xsl:if test="not(zipPlus/@xsl:nil='true')">
                <xsl:value-of select="zipPlus"/>
            </xsl:if>
```

Result XML

```
            <zipPlus/>
            or
            <zipPlus>123456</zipPlus>
```